# ValueError at /edit/3 The view main_panel.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add an edit button to my project and gives me an error.

The following code is my *views.py* file.

```
def edit(request, list_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    return render(request, 'main_panel/edit.html', {'item': item})
```

This is my *edit.html*,

```
{% extends 'main_panel/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

 {% if item  %}
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}


    <input type="search" value="{{ item.name }}" name="name">
    <input type="search" value="{{ item.choice_field }}" name="choice_field">
    <input type="search" value="{{ item.product }}" name="product">
    <input type="search" value="{{ item.avans }}" name="avans">
    <input type="search" value="{{ item.total_price }}" name="total_price">
    <input type="search" value="{{ item.status }}" name="status">

    <button type="submit">Kaydet</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my *urls.py*,

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
  path('delete/<list_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
  path('edit/<list_id>', views.edit, name='edit')
]
```

which gives me the following error:

> ValueError at /edit/3
>       The view main_panel.views.edit didn't return an HttpResponse object.
>       It returned None instead.

When I click the *submit* button after I edit my data it gives me the error. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your view receive a POST request and the form is not valid, the function does not execute an explicit return statement and returns the default value of `None`.

I suggest you to look at this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view

See how how the last line is a default return statement for GET requests and not valid POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **mg**, if the `form.is_valid()` is not `true`, it will not implicitly `return` something. it will leave you with `None`

```
def edit(request, list_id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
  item = List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
  form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)

  if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     return redirect('home')
  return redirect('error_page') # or basically any other return maybe HttpResponse
```